# Grails Spring Security - using other properties in authentication

Tags: authentication, grails, spring-security

I just want to ask if it is possible to use other properties excluding username & password of a domain class for logging in?

For example I have a `Person` domain class that has a `one-to-one` relationship to `Account` domain class. And I want to authenticate my user using their `firstName` & `birthDate` properties found in `Person` domain class.

Is there a configuration that I can do to make this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. That's possible.

You have to write a customized `authentication-provider`, in which you may take parameters you like to do the authentication.

As an example, you may have something like this:

```
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username){
        //You have to override this method to have your desired action
        //If those criteria are not satisfied you may return null
        //Otherwise have an UserDetails filled and returned
        org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User userDetails = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getIsActive(), true, true, true, getAuthorities(user));
        return userDetails

    }
```

And in your bean configuration, use your own `authentication-provider` like this:

```
<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="myUserDetailsService"/>
</sec:authentication-manager>
```